# Change image color and luminosity while keeping shadows with python

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I have a photo representing different elements, and I have a binary mask for each of the elements.
My goal is to change the color of elements at wills, while keeping shadows.

Although changing "hue" is necessary ([example of re-coloring changing hue](https://towardsdatascience.com/color-swapping-techniques-in-image-processing-fe594b3ca31a)), it is not sufficient, as I may have black or white elements for which I want to match the desired color. Thus, for these elements, I should change luminosity too, but still keep shadows. And here another issue arises: strong black or white elements may have S and V or L values ([in HSV or HSL color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)) that are all very near to 0 or 255.

I have tested many different versions of a coloring function I've built, which you may find below (note 4 versions of the function, named "update_color{version_num}"):

```
def update_color(in_img, rgb: tuple, approach: int = 1, img_format: str = 'rgb', mask=None, restore_mask=None):
    # Convert Input image to hsv
    if img_format == 'rgb':
        img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    elif img_format == 'bgr':
        img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    elif img_format == 'hsv':
        img_hsv = in_img.copy()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"'img_format' must be one in {'rgb', 'bgr', 'hsv'}. Got '{img_format}'.")

    # Set mask when not provided
    if mask is None:
        mask = np.ones_like(img_hsv[:, :, 0], dtype='bool')

    # Exit if mask is empty
    if np.sum(mask) <= 0:
        return in_img.copy()

    # Restore S and V channels in mask
    mean_s = -1
    mean_v = -1

    # Create fake color matrix
    color_matrix = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype='uint8')
    color_matrix[0, 0, ::-1] = rgb

    # Extract H, S, V
    H, S, V = cv2.cvtColor(color_matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[0, 0, :]

    if approach == 1:
        # Extract channels from image
        h_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 0].copy().astype('int32')
        s_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 1].copy().astype('int32')
        v_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 2].copy().astype('int32')

        # Update H
        h_channel[mask] = H

        # Update S
        s_channel_mask = s_channel[mask].copy()
        if mean_s < 0:
            mean_s = int(np.mean(s_channel[restore_mask])) if restore_mask is not None else int(np.mean(s_channel[mask]))
        scale = (255 - v_channel[mask]) * (255 - s_channel_mask) / 240**2
        s_channel[mask] += ((S - mean_s) * np.clip(scale, 0, 1)).astype('int32')
        s_channel = np.clip(s_channel, 0, 255)

        # Update V
        if mean_v < 0:
            mean_v = int(np.mean(v_channel[restore_mask])) if restore_mask is not None else int(np.mean(v_channel[mask]))
        v_channel[mask] += V - mean_v
        v_channel = np.clip(v_channel, 0, 255)

        # Create output HSV image
        out_img_hsv = np.stack((h_channel, s_channel, v_channel), axis=2).astype(np.uint8)

    elif approach == 2:
        # Extract channels from image
        h_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 0].copy().astype('int32')
        s_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 1].copy().astype('int32')
        v_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 2].copy().astype('int32')

        # Update H
        h_channel[mask] = H

        # Update S
        adjust_s = np.max(rgb) - np.min(rgb)
        if adjust_s < 10:
            S *= adjust_s / 10
        s_channel[mask] = (s_channel[mask].astype('float32') * S / 255).astype('int32')
        s_channel = np.clip(s_channel, 0, 255)

        # Update V
        if mean_v < 0:
            mean_v = int(np.mean(v_channel[restore_mask])) if restore_mask is not None else int(
                np.mean(v_channel[mask]))
        v_mask = v_channel.copy()
        v_mask_min = np.clip(v_mask - 85, v_mask // 5, 255)
        v_mask_max = np.clip(v_mask + 85, 0, 255)
        v_channel[mask] += V - mean_v
        v_channel = np.clip(v_channel, v_mask_min, v_mask_max)

        # Create output HSV image
        out_img_hsv = np.stack((h_channel, s_channel, v_channel), axis=2).astype(np.uint8)

    elif approach == 3:
        # Extract channels from image
        h_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 0].copy().astype('int32')
        s_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 1].copy().astype('int32')
        v_channel = img_hsv[:, :, 2].copy().astype('int32')

        # Update H
        h_channel[mask] = H

        # Update S
        s_channel[mask] = S

        # Update V
        if mean_v < 0:
            mean_v = int(np.mean(v_channel[restore_mask])) if restore_mask is not None else int(
                np.mean(v_channel[mask]))
        v_channel[mask] += V - mean_v
        v_channel = np.clip(v_channel, 0, 255)

        # Create output HSV image
        out_img_hsv = np.stack((h_channel, s_channel, v_channel), axis=2).astype(np.uint8)

    else:
        img_hls = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

        # Extract H, L, S and channels
        H, L, S = cv2.cvtColor(color_matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)[0, 0, :]
        h_channel = img_hls[:, :, 0].copy().astype('int32')
        l_channel = img_hls[:, :, 1].copy().astype('int32')
        s_channel = img_hls[:, :, 2].copy().astype('int32')

        h_channel[mask] = H
        l_channel[mask] += (L - np.mean(l_channel[mask])).astype('int32')
        l_channel = np.clip(l_channel, 0, 255)
        s_channel[mask] = S

        out_img_hls = np.stack((h_channel, l_channel, s_channel), axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
        out_img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.cvtColor(out_img_hls, cv2.COLOR_HLS2BGR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Move back to selected format
    if img_format == 'rgb':
        out_img = cv2.cvtColor(out_img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    elif img_format == 'bgr':
        out_img = cv2.cvtColor(out_img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    elif img_format == 'hsv':
        out_img = out_img_hsv.copy()
    else:
        out_img = in_img.copy()
    out_img[~mask] = in_img[~mask]

    return out_img
```

To test a single function it is sufficient to load an `image` and set a color `rgb = (50, 0, 0)`, then call `update_color1(image, rgb, img_format='bgr')`. However, in this case, all elements are updated at once: light elements will remain lighter and dark elements will remain darker.

Instead, I call the update function on one element at a time. Some approaches produce good results only if original element color is convenient (e.g. if element has a middle luminosity and a high saturation), while some other approaches produce a color that is more similar across elements but it is generally not satifying (e.g. shadows are completely lost on some elements).

I need to have the same shadowed color regardless of the element underneath, and keep continuity between a single element (e.g. in my use case, one element may be split in two masks, and the result of applying mask1 and mask2 must be the same of that applying mask1+mask2, so for instance taking the `np.mean` of a mask may not be enough since the two masks may have different mean values).

---

Here a test code and images.

*Original image*
[image: Original image]

*Results* (note that there is an overlap over two masks, but it is not the main issue here)
[image: Result applying method 1]
[image: Result applying method 2]
[image: Result applying method 4]
[image: Result applying method 3]

*Test code* (masks are not perfect, but they are much easier to share)

```
# Load image
image = cv2.imread(r".\colored-coins.jpg")
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Extract mask
colors = [(180, 122, 100), (12, 28, 245), (255, 110, 159), (25, 124, 181),
          (125, 132, 0), (116, 31, 2), (110, 110, 80), (8, 56, 30)]
h_values = [colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*cc)[0]*180 for cc in colors]
masks = [(image_hsv[:,:,0] < h + 20) & (image_hsv[:,:,0] > h - 20) & (image_hsv[:,:,2] > 10) for h in h_values]
masks[0][:,320:] = False
masks[1][260:, :] = False
masks[1][:, 620:] = False
masks[2][350:, :] = False
masks[2][:, :-430] = False
masks[3][:155, :] = False
masks[3][520:, :] = False
masks[3][:, :445] = False
masks[4][:300, :] = False
masks[4][-75:, :] = False
masks[4][:, :-350] = False
masks[5][:-180, :] = False
masks[6][:260, :] = False
masks[6][-170:, :] = False
masks[6][:, :320] = False
masks[6][:, -350:] = False
masks[7][:350, :] = False
masks[7][:, 330:] = False

# Update color of image
new_image1, new_image2, new_image3, new_image4 = image.copy(), image.copy(), image.copy(), image.copy()
for mask in masks:
    new_image1 = update_color(new_image1, (50, 0, 0), approach=1, img_format='bgr', mask=mask)
    new_image2 = update_color(new_image2, (50, 0, 0), approach=2, img_format='bgr', mask=mask)
    new_image3 = update_color(new_image3, (50, 0, 0), approach=3, img_format='bgr', mask=mask)
    new_image4 = update_color(new_image4, (50, 0, 0), approach=4, img_format='bgr', mask=mask)

cv2.imshow(f"1", new_image1)
cv2.imshow(f"2", new_image2)
cv2.imshow(f"3", new_image3)
cv2.imshow(f"4", new_image4)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you have four functions that hardly differ, if at all. it would be good coding practice, and help your question, to refactor the common parts out of each. and perhaps work to simplify it further. please review [mre]. -- and your masks are simply rectangular, which will cause overlap with parts of other objects. you need a picture containing label "colors" (grayscale, lossless compression) where regions are defined by pixels, not rectangles

Comment: You're right, the functions have minimal changes, but yet it's easy to get one and test it alone. I'll try to update them as you proposed, thank you for your advice. The masks I use are much more complex, but I needed a way to easily provide them to you. If you see them, they are actually not rectangular at all, still I crop them to cut out some of the noise. There is a single overlap in the example above, but it shall not be the main concern here when working for a solution.